# How can I omit an application from showing up as frequently used in the start menu?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I used to use a certain application very frequently (WinSCP), but I now seldom use it.

As such, I explicitly removed it from the start-menu's frequently used list. However, now if I use it even just once, it jumps to the top of the list and I have to remove it manually again.

Is there a way I can tell Windows to simply omit the application from the start menu list?

Comment: Have you tried the technique that works in XP as detailed here - http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5852439.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5852439.html) (admittedly for XP) you need to add a new key to the registry:

1. Launch the Registry Editor
   (Regedit.exe).
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications.`
3. [If there's not already an entry for the application] Right-click the `Applications` key and select `New | Key`. Name the key the
   same name as the application's
   executable file.
4. Right-click your new key and select `New | String Value`. Name the string value `NoStartPage`.
5. Close the Registry Editor.
6. Reboot or log off and log back on for the change to take effect.